# Error for classifier.predict in tensorflow (Shape in shape_and_slice spec does not match)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and to understand the basics I am following a tutorial. When copying this code (https://github.com/random-forests/tutorials/blob/master/ep7.ipynb) and trying to execute it I am getting an error.

> W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Invalid argument: Shape in shape_and_slice spec [1,10] does not match the shape stored in checkpoint: [784,10]
>   Traceback (most recent call last):...

The command which seems to be responsible is the follwing:

```
 classifier.predict(test_data[0])
```

Can you tell me the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try

```
classifier.predict(np.array([test_data[0]], dtype=float), as_iterable=False)
```

That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

side note : you have to increase the memory on the raspberry pi to be able to run the example ( and add plt.show() in the display function )

learned it from this site
https://qiita.com/mgr206/items/9fc0de88ff9547372cac
no need for japanese , just check the commands